# arcsde huge size file upload into Oracle spatial

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, oracle-spatial, file-geodatabase

I have 35million records (tomtom multinet) of file gdb file in my desktop machine. I need to upload this file into Oracle spatial as SDO_geometry file.

I already tested the connection with small size file gdb file  and it is success.

Is there any best practice here to upload this huge file (from a desktop machine -windows 7 to oracle ?

my env: arcgis desktop 9.3.1 (sp2) and arcsde (arccatalog and arsde are in same machine), oracle 10g (db is in different location).

Or, whether i have to upload it as splittted files (5m rows each) into oracle spatial, then doing append in a file through arccatalog. I have default dbtune.sde file, commit interval 1000.

Pls. share your experience in this.

Comment: Hi, I have made the commit interval as 10000.  The 48mn rows (9gb) got loaded in 20hrs.  Also, before loading the fGDB, i have removed the spatial index created by the arccatalog.

Comment: It looks like you resolved this unaided.  I think it would be useful for you to copy your solution from the current Comment to an Answer that you can then self-Accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the commit interval as 10,000 in the sde config. Around 48 millions rows (9gb - road network) got loaded in ~20hrs. 
Also, before loading the fGDB, i have removed the spatial indexes created bfore using Arc Catalog